# Why do progress bars not load in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have been devloping a website but can not get a progress bar of any sorts to load in Internet Explorer. I tried both the basic progress bar in html, as well as a more complex CSS one, both of which did not work. I have 3 scripts, the first of which is the html code for the basic progress bar, as well as 4 of the more complex ones. The second script is the CSS styling for the more complex bar. Finally I have my run file which is used to live update the site I am working on. I am running the site on Apache 2.4.10 and it functions properly in both Firefox and Google Chrome. When trying in Internet Explorer, all that loads is a single black rectangle, instead of 4 actual bars, and one of the smaller progress bars. Please let me know if you see the flaw in my code or if you have the fix to the problem.

This is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="progressbarstyle.css">
</head>
<title> Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>  
    <progress max="100" value="10"></progress><br/>
    <div class="meter red">
        <span id="progress-load" style="height: 60%" > </span>
    </div>
    <div class="meter red">
        <span id="progress-load"  style="height: 60%" > </span>
    </div>
    <div class="meter red">
        <span id="progress-load" style="height: 40%" > </span>
    </div>
    <div class="meter red">
        <span id="progress-load" style="height: 50%" > </span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
<script>
```

This is the CSS

```
p {color: white; 
background-color: black;}
body {background-color: #F5F5DC; }



.meter { 
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #555;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow   : inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  box-shadow        : inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

.progress-load {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
     -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
         -moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;
             border-top-right-radius: 20px;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
   -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
          -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
       -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(43,194,83);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    center right,
    center right,
    color-stop(0, rgb(43,194,83)),
    color-stop(1, rgb(84,240,84))
    );
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    center right,
    rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
    rgb(84,240,84) 69%
    );
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
    center right,
    rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
    rgb(84,240,84) 69%
    );
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(
    center right,
    rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
    rgb(84,240,84) 69%
    );
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(
    center right,
    rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
    rgb(84,240,84) 69%
    );
  -webkit-box-shadow: 
    inset 0 2px 9px  rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 
    inset 0 2px 9px  rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  overflow: hidden;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;

}

.red > span {
  background-color: #f0a3a3;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,
    left top,left bottom,color-stop(0.#f0a3a3),color-stop(1, #f42323));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #f0a3a3, #f42323);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #f0a3a3, #f42323);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #f0a3a3, #f42323);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #f0a3a3, #f42323);
}

.meter > span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background-image: 
    -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, 
      color-stop(.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), 
      color-stop(.25, transparent), color-stop(.5, transparent), 
      color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), 
      color-stop(.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), 
      color-stop(.75, transparent), to(transparent)
    );
  background-image: 
    -webkit-linear-gradient(
      -45deg, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, 
      transparent 25%, 
      transparent 50%, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, 
      transparent 75%, 
      transparent
    );
  background-image: 
    -moz-linear-gradient(
      -45deg, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, 
      transparent 25%, 
      transparent 50%, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, 
      transparent 75%, 
      transparent
    );
  background-image: 
    -ms-linear-gradient(
      -45deg, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, 
      transparent 25%, 
      transparent 50%, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, 
      transparent 75%, 
      transparent
    );
  background-image: 
    -o-linear-gradient(
      -45deg, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, 
      transparent 25%, 
      transparent 50%, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, 
      transparent 75%, 
      transparent
    );
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
  -moz-background-size:    50px 50px;
  background-size:         50px 50px;
  -webkit-animation: move 2s linear infinite;
     -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
         -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
             border-top-right-radius: 8px;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
   -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
          -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
       -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
              border-top-left-radius: 20px;
           border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And finally here is my run file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">

</style>

<script>

function showCustomer(str)
{



var xmlhttp;    
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari     php<!-- include('test.php');--> ?>
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","Progress.html",true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader( "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT" );
xmlhttp.send(null);
//showCustomer('ALFKI');
setTimeout(function(){showCustomer('load')}, 1500);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="showCustomer('Load')">

<div id="txtHint"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Internet Explorer 11

Comment: In your post some **span** are open without `>` like this `<span id="progress-load" style="height: 60%"  </span>`

Comment: Icaro thank you so much! That finally made them appear at least! they are now on the page and have a very pinkish red filling on them. They appear in chrome as a bright red with striping and roudning elements on them. Any idea why the rest of the CSS elements are not being applied? I edited my code as per your suggestion above.

Comment: Try http://validator.w3.org/ and see what it finds.

Comment: Another question if I may. I have variables defined in php from a database. Do you know how to set the height of these bars based off a variable such as $totalvalue